# Import js library in polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I'm facing an issue I want to know how can I import an external javascript "library/ file" to my polymer project.
I want to use the htmlToPdf.js library in polymer. but I can't call the functions on the htmlToPdf.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to reuse the library in different components, then it is better to create an import component

```
<!-- htmlToPdf-import.html -->
<script src="../htmlToPdf/htmlToPdf.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- my-component.html -->

<link rel="import" href="./htmlToPdf-import.html">

<dom-module id="my-component">
  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyComponent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-component';
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyComponent.is, MyComponent);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import it in a Polymer component using a regular `<script>` tag.

Comment: Using a  script tag inside the  element im will to make the  function calls was giving " is not a function".